# Maven - ignore ANSI color escaping chars in grep search

Tags: grep, maven, ansi

I find that sometimes, ANSI escaping chars in `mvn` output prevents me to do this search with grep:

```
mvn | grep -P "\[INFO\]"
```

I have to use `"\[.*INFO.*\]"` to get results.

How to disable processing the ANSI escaping chars? I think there is some config for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's also `--batch-mode` (`-B`) for mvn which makes the output more suitable for e.g. CI or searches likes this as it's more automated.

Or, a generic solution, strip ANSI colors in any command by using [ansi2txt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ansi2txt.1.html) tool, which is part of [colorized-logs](https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs) package:

```
mvn | ansi2txt | grep -P "\[INFO\]"
```

Comment: Thanks, those are also good alternatives. For local I want to search and check color, for CI maybe `-B` makes more sense. And ansi2txt is a more general solution, in environments where I can install it.

Comment: @WesternGun: If the output isn't too huge, you could let it output the full text on your terminal in colour, and use your terminal's search within scrollback history.  (control-shift-f in KDE's Konsole.  Various other terminals have that feature, including `screen` or `tmux` which you can run inside any terminal.)  The answer you posted runs `mvn` with uncolorized output when piping to grep, so you're still not getting colourized output through grep :/

Comment: Yes you are right. After piping to grep the color is not preserved. But I use it in a script so maybe that does not matter. I see surprisingly this answer got more votes than I imagined and you have more upvotes than me so let's accept yours! Good job.

Answer (score 6):

Seems `mvn` has a config of `-Dstyle.color=auto` to ignore the ANSI color escaping chars so that I don't need to alter the pattern in my script to add `.*`.

```bash
# define an alias including the color settings
$ alias mvn='/opt/data/maven/bin/mvn -Dstyle.color=auto'

# use the alias in the script
$ mvn | grep -P "\[INFO\]"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.132 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-25T14:05:13+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Presumably "auto" means use color only when stdout is a terminal. I'm surprised this isn't the default. And if it has a config file you should be able to enable it there, rather than the alias (which won't be used in scripts).

Comment: Yes I think the same, strangely not like grep color settings, which is put into environment vars. We have "always/auto/never" in this settings.